# Intellisense is configured properly but it doesn't pop-up as I type

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

My PC went down today before I could shut VS 2010 down.  Now Intellisense no longer pops up as I type.  In addition, when I click on Edit | Intellisense, the menu I see does not contain the menu that lets you clean up the usings in your source file.

I have reviewed the Intellisense options in my copy of VS 2010 and they are set up properly.  That is, when I go to Tools | Options and then choose Text Editor, C#, General, Auto List Members is checked off and so is Parameter Information.  Also, on Intellisens, Show Completion List after a character is typed is also checked.

Yet Intellisense doesn't pop up until I hit Ctrl-J or Ctrl-space.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File this one under stupid programmer tricks.  Turns out that I had a source file open in a solution other than the one it belonged to.  When I closed that solution and opened the proper one, Intellisense started working fine.

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling and re-enabling the IntelliSense from Tools | Options | Text Editor | C# | IntelliSense  : uncheck the complete list and Apply, then check it back again and apply.

If this doesn't help you might need to repair you VS2010 installation.

Comment: I tried that several times.  Made no difference.  Now I know why.  See my answer.  I'm upvoting you anyway because it's a step that makes sense to try.